# How to create pascal variable for FastReport?

Tags: fastreport

I'm trying to make a variable on Fast Report version 2.5

I can only use the old version and trying make an object to be used for report.
I saw the new version of Fast Report and they have a code editor.Is the version 2.5 also have this functionality?

I'm trying to test this:

[image]

Currently [MyVariable] can't be used as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare MyVariable in the report data dictionary and use such script:

```
begin
  MyVariable := '''' + 'Hello' + '''';
end
```

Comment: should I insert it in expression builder in data dictionary?